# Python thread and global interpreter lock when access same object

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

I am trying to understand python thread and how it works.

From my understanding, I know that there is GIL(Global Interpreter Lock) to prevent two thread to access memory at the same time.

This is pretty reasonable, even though it slows down the program.

But the code below, show unexpected result.

```
import thread, time
mylist = [[0,1]]

def listTo300Elem(id):
    while len(mylist) < 300:
        mylist.append([id, mylist[-1][1]+1])

thread.start_new_thread(listTo300Elem, (1,))
thread.start_new_thread(listTo300Elem, (2,))
thread.start_new_thread(listTo300Elem, (3,))
thread.start_new_thread(listTo300Elem, (4,))
thread.start_new_thread(listTo300Elem, (5,))
thread.start_new_thread(listTo300Elem, (6,))
thread.start_new_thread(listTo300Elem, (7,))

time.sleep(5)

print mylist
print len(mylist)
```

And the result is

[[0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9], [1, 10], [1, 11], [1, 12], [1, 13], [1, 14], [1, 15], [1, 16], [1, 17], [1, 18], [1, 19], [1, 20], [1, 21], [1, 22], [1, 23], [1, 24], [1, 25], [1, 26], [1, 27], [1, 28], [1, 29], [1, 30], [1, 31], [1, 32], [1, 33], [1, 34], [1, 35], [1, 36], [1, 37], [1, 38], [1, 39], [1, 40], [1, 41], [1, 42], [1, 43], [1, 44], [1, 45], [1, 46], [1, 47], [1, 48], [1, 49], [1, 50], [1, 51], [1, 52], [1, 53], [1, 54], [1, 55], [1, 56], [1, 57], [1, 58], [1, 59], [1, 60], [1, 61], [1, 62], [1, 63], [1, 64], [1, 65], [1, 66], [1, 67], [1, 68], [1, 69], [1, 70], [1, 71], [1, 72], [2, 73], [2, 74], [2, 75], [2, 76], [2, 77], [2, 78], [2, 79], [5, 80], [5, 81], [5, 82], [5, 83], [5, 84], [5, 85], [5, 86], [5, 87], [5, 88], [5, 89], [5, 90], [5, 91], [5, 92], [5, 93], [5, 94], [3, 95], [3, 96], [3, 97], [3, 98], [3, 99], [3, 100], [3, 101], [3, 102], [3, 103], [3, 104], [3, 105], [3, 106], [3, 107], [3, 108], [3, 109], [3, 110], [3, 111], [3, 112], [3, 113], [3, 114], [3, 115], [3, 116], [3, 117], [7, 118], [7, 119], [7, 120], [7, 121], [7, 122], [7, 123], [7, 124], [2, 80], [2, 81], [2, 82], [2, 83], [2, 84], [2, 85], [2, 86], [2, 87], [2, 88], [2, 89], [2, 90], [2, 91], [2, 92], [2, 93], [2, 94], [2, 95], [2, 96], [2, 97], [2, 98], [2, 99], [2, 100], [2, 101], [2, 102], [2, 103], [2, 104], [2, 105], [2, 106], [2, 107], [2, 108], [2, 109], [2, 110], [2, 111], [2, 112], [2, 113], [2, 114], [2, 115], [2, 116], [2, 117], [2, 118], [2, 119], [2, 120], [2, 121], [2, 122], [2, 123], [2, 124], [2, 125], [2, 126], [2, 127], [2, 128], [2, 129], [2, 130], [2, 131], [2, 132], [2, 133], [2, 134], [2, 135], [2, 136], [2, 137], [2, 138], [2, 139], [2, 140], [2, 141], [7, 125], [7, 126], [7, 127], [7, 128], [7, 129], [7, 130], [7, 131], [7, 132], [7, 133], [7, 134], [7, 135], [7, 136], [7, 137], [7, 138], [7, 139], [7, 140], [7, 141], [7, 142], [7, 143], [7, 144], [7, 145], [7, 146], [7, 147], [7, 148], [7, 149], [7, 150], [7, 151], [7, 152], [7, 153], [7, 154], [7, 155], [7, 156], [7, 157], [7, 158], [7, 159], [7, 160], [7, 161], [7, 162], [7, 163], [7, 164], [7, 165], [7, 166], [7, 167], [7, 168], [7, 169], [7, 170], [7, 171], [6, 172], [6, 173], [6, 174], [6, 175], [6, 176], [6, 177], [6, 178], [3, 179], [3, 180], [3, 181], [3, 182], [3, 183], [3, 184], [3, 185], [3, 186], [3, 187], [3, 188], [3, 189], [3, 190], [3, 191], [3, 192], [3, 193], [3, 194], [3, 195], [3, 196], [3, 197], [3, 198], [3, 199], [3, 200], [3, 201], [7, 202], [7, 203], [7, 204], [7, 205], [7, 206], [7, 207], [7, 208], [7, 209], [1, 210], [1, 211], [1, 212], [1, 213], [1, 214], [1, 215], [1, 216], [1, 217], [1, 218], [1, 219], [1, 220], [1, 221], [1, 222], [1, 223], [1, 224], [1, 225], [1, 226], [1, 227], [1, 228], [1, 229], [1, 230], [1, 231], [1, 232], [1, 233], [1, 234], [1, 235], [1, 236], [1, 237], [1, 238], [3, 239], [5, 240], [2, 142], [6, 179]]
304

From my understanding, the result must be in order due to GIL, but they are not.

Can I get explanation for this example and further items to study?

Comment: what is it confused you? len(mylist) = 304?

Comment: Why they are not in order, even though python has GIL? And also why is the length over than 300? If there is no GIL, I may expect this, but python has it. Then why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you expect? That one thread add one item, after that another thread and etc.? Than why so many threads, if they work by one at once? Threads are trying to work simultaneously with one object. But since the GIL is not a good thing to do parallel computing, they do it so ugly.

To get more undestanding how GIL works, you may add logging.

```
logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s] %(threadName)-12s %(message)s", level=logging.DEBUG, filename='log.log')

def listTo300Elem(id):
    list_len = len(mylist)
    while list_len < 300:
        item = mylist[-1][1]+1]
        mylist.append([id, item])
        logging.debug('Len = {}, item {} added'.format(list_len, item))
        list_len = len(mylist)
    logging.debug('Len = {}, exit'.format(list_len, item))
```

So, threading in python is not suitable for all cases.

Comment: Why does it output results in order, when I add your code for logging in method? Is this because logging kills some time for each thread?

Comment: quantum uncertainty principle :)